# I am trying to add a value , when a person have the right answer

Tags: python, function, otree

I am trying to make a code in Python for a Otree aplication.

The main idea is to add $20 to a fixed payment when a person have the same answer that I put in my constants.

For example in this code I have a value of 3 in Constants.retemv if a person put a response of 3 in the J11 form the will get the $20

I try to use the next code, payment is a constant with a $20 value.

```
def set_payoff(self):
        self.payoff = Constants.participation_fee + Constants.iat 
        if self.J11 == Constants.retemv:
            self.payoff += Constants.payment
```

I expect the output of $45 when the people put the same answer that my retemv”

Comment: There is not enough context to figure out what is going on in your question.  you don't provide the actual answer.   Please consider adding more details to your question.

Comment: I am sorry, I try adding some context.

Comment: I think your issue is that you are trying to initialize the `payoff` attribute in a function that is probably called more than once which will always reset the value in payoff even after the  `J11` was one time equal to `retemv`, are you sure payoff isn't something that should be in `__init__()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
def set_payoff(self):
    if self.J11 == Constants.retemv:
        self.payoff = Constants.participation_fee + Constants.iat + Constants.payment
    else:
        self.payoff = Constants.participation_fee + Constants.iat
```